# "Resetting" an array with a button (in swift/Xcode)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm just starting out with code so forgive me if this is pretty basic.  I am nearly done with my first app, which I've used storyboards to build.  For now, it's a simple "piggy bank" where I enter the amount of tips I make at work on a particular day on the main screen, which then gets added to a running total on a second screen.  These "tip" values are all stored in an array.  I want to make a button on the second screen that removes all values in the array.

I will post my code below, but it seems if I use `.removeAll()` along with a `saveDefaults` and `loadDefaults`, values will be removed from the array but only after I close and reopen the app.  If I press the button but continue using the app, values will continue to be added to the array without removing any.  I would like if the button removed all values while the app is still open and being used.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Here is the code for the "running total" screen, which is where I have the code for the button in question:

```
import UIKit

class TipTotalView: UIViewController {
    
    

    @IBOutlet weak var totalTip: UILabel?
    
    var tipToText = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        totalTip?.text = tipToText
    }
    
    @IBAction func emptyPiggy(_ sender: Any) {
        let cs = CalcScreen(nibName: "CalcScreen", bundle: nil)
        cs.tipArray.removeAll()
        cs.saveDefaults()
        cs.loadDefaults()
        print(cs.tipArray)
    }
    
}
```

And here's the rest of the code for the main screen, which may be relevant (possibly the addToday button at the bottom is important?).

```
UIKit



class CalcScreen: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tipAmount: UILabel!
    
    var tipArray: [Int] = []
        
        var tipArrayTotal: Int {
            return tipArray.reduce(0, +)
        }

    func loadDefaults()
    {
       tipArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "tipArray") as? [Int] ?? []
    }

    func saveDefaults()
    {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(tipArray, forKey: "tipArray")
    }
   
    var tip = String()
    
    let vc = TipTotalView(nibName: "TipTotalView", bundle: nil)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadDefaults()
    }
    
    func clearTip() {
        tip = String()
        tipAmount.text = "0"
    }
    
    func addToTip (value: String) {
        tip += value
        tipAmount.text = String(tip)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func zero(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "0")
    }
    
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: Any) {
        clearTip()
    }
    
    @IBAction func one(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "1")
    }
    
    @IBAction func two(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "2")
    }
    
    @IBAction func three(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "3")
    }
    
    @IBAction func four(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "4")
    }
    
    @IBAction func five(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "5")
    }
    
    @IBAction func six(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "6")
    }
    
    @IBAction func seven(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "7")
    }
    
    @IBAction func eight(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "8")
    }
    
    @IBAction func nine(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: "9")
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func addToday(_ sender: Any) {
        let tipNum = Int(tip) ?? 0
        tipArray.append(tipNum)
        saveDefaults()
        vc.tipToText = String(tipArrayTotal)
        vc.totalTip?.text = vc.tipToText
        clearTip()
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        print(tipArray)
        print(tipArrayTotal)
        print(vc.tipToText)
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: In your "emptyPiggy" method you are creating a new instance. And that instance has a new copy of tipArray. So the solution would be passing the reference of "CalcScreen" while pushing your controller from "addToday" method. From there you can reset the tipArray.

Comment: @AliAsad is right. If you are using a storyboard segue to go from TipTotalView to CalcScreen you need to get a reference to the existing CalcScreen. let cs = ... is making a new CalcScreen without displaying it. Look into prepareForSegue to call methods on the existing screen

Comment: @AliAsad thank you for your response, I appreciate your knowledge.  Someone had answered (and then deleted it, for some reason) to put `loadDefaults()` in a `ViewDidAppear()` which actually resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate pattern for update data from MainController:

```
import UIKit

class TipTotalView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var totalTip: UILabel?

    var tipToText = ""
    var delegate: MainControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       totalTip?.text = tipToText
    }

    @IBAction func emptyPiggy(_ sender: Any) {
       delegate?.emptyPiggy()
       self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }   
}
```

Create MainControllerDelegate inside CalcScreen File:

```
UIKit

protocol DataUpdateDelegate {
   func updateData()
}

class CalcScreen: UIViewController {

..
.. // Your code

    @IBAction func addToday(_ sender: Any) {
        let tipNum = Int(tip) ?? 0
        tipArray.append(tipNum)
        saveDefaults()
        vc.tipToText = String(tipArrayTotal)
        vc.totalTip?.text = vc.tipToText
        vc.delegate = self
        clearTip()
    
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension CalcScreen: MainControllerDelegate {
     func emptyPiggy() {
          tipArray.removeAll()
          saveDefaults()
          loadDefaults()
     }
}
```